# Using the home or side button of the Apple Watch in a shortcut

Tags: apple-watch, shortcuts-app, apple-watch.app

I'm currently trying to create a shortcut that skips to the next song in the Music app when I press the home (or maybe side) button. Unfortunately, I haven't found the action for these 2 buttons on the Shortcuts app.

Is it really not possible to use these buttons in a shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only button that can be used in Shortcuts is the Action Button and it’s only available (as of this post) on the [Apple Watch Ultra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213335).

> …use the Action button, which gives you quick access to some of your favorite Apple Watch Ultra features.

Shortcuts is specifically listed as one of the functions of the Action Button.

> #### What can the Action button do? You can configure actions related to these apps and features:
>
> - Workout
> - Stopwatch
> - Waypoint
> - Backtrack
> - Dive
> - Flashlight
> - **Shortcut**

<sup>Emphasis Mine</sup>

#### TL;DR

You can’t assign a shortcut to the crown or side button on the Apple Watch. The only button that can be assigned to a shortcut is the Action button available only on the Apple Watch Ultra.